# stack protector does not throw error with strcpy()

Tags: stack

I'm testing an example of stack protector from ARM reference document (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0616/armclang-Reference/armclang-Command-line-Options/-fstack-protector---fstack-protector-all---fstack-protector-strong---fno-stack-protector), which has code like:

```c
    // main.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    void *__stack_chk_guard = (void *)0xdeadbeef;
    
    void __stack_chk_fail(void)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack smashing detected.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    void get_input(char *data);
    
    
    char main(void)
    {
        char buffer[8] = { 0 };
        char *overflowed = &buffer[8];
    
        get_input(buffer);
        // =============================================================
        // The following line is added by me. This triggers stack smashing,
        // but strcpy() should also trigger stack smashing detect.
        // *overflowed = 0xFF;
        printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("buffer addr: 0x%08x\n", buffer[8]);
        // =============================================================
        return buffer[0];
    }
    
    // get.c
    #include <string.h>
    
    void get_input(char *data)
    {
        strcpy(data, "01234567");
    }
```

I think this code intends to make stack overflow by accessing extra memory(buffer[8]) for NULL character using strcpy(). But the actual behavior is that no messages are thrown at all.

```sh
➜  stack_protector gcc main.c get.c -o test -fstack-protector-all
➜  stack_protector ./test
buffer: 01234567
buffer addr: 0x00000000
```

I checked that stack protector cannot detect smashing error if the stack size is smaller than 8 bytes, but this is not the case I think. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Your stack guard value is `0x00000000deadbeef` and the buffer overflow writes a 0, so it's possible that the 0 byte just overwrote a pre-existing 0, which has no net effect and doesn't trigger detection. Another possibility is that the `overflowed` variable itself is occupying stack space, and your attempted corruption of the stack guard actually corrupted the `overflowed` variable. The `printf` calls you added may also alter the stack layout. Step through the code in a debugger to see where the overflow byte is written, and then step through the detector code to see why it didn't detect it.

Comment: I've just checked your suggestions. I tried 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but overflow wasn't detected. It seems that the detection still does not work even after removing all printf and *overflowed. As you said, I will step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: @RaymondChen I checked that "fs:0x28" is set wrongly at the beginning of execution. It always set like 0x22e7b9ffbc9cb9"00". Lower 8 bits are always set to zero. I think there is a bug related to setting stackguard value from my Linux distro. Please note me I'm thinking correctly.

Comment: I added one more character on the end of the strcpy, and the signal occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped through the code with a debugger and figured out the stack guard value was not set properly. Its lower 8bits are always set to zero, which results in detection miss.

Since fs:0x28 register is set from the operating system, I reported this to my Linux distro's bug tracker.

--
(Added) I looked into Kernel code and there is code like:

```
/*
 * On 64-bit architectures, protect against non-terminated C string overflows
 * by zeroing out the first byte of the canary; this leaves 56 bits of entropy.
 */
#ifdef CONFIG_64BIT
# ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#  define CANARY_MASK 0xffffffffffffff00UL
# else /* big endian, 64 bits: */
#  define CANARY_MASK 0x00ffffffffffffffUL
# endif
#else /* 32 bits: */
# define CANARY_MASK 0xffffffffUL
#endif
```

Basically, initializing the first byte of the canary to zero is intended by kernel code. This is a kind of boundary that secures canary value from printing out. Due to \0 character, we can prevent canary value from printing out and this is the reason that I cannot reproduce stack overflow error with NULL character using strcpy().